# Characteristic function of a measurable set.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X=L^p[0,1]$ $(1\leq p<\infty)$ be the Lebesgue space of p-integrable real functions on $[0,1]$. Let $D\subseteq [0,1]$ be measurable subset. The characteristic functions $\chi_D$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
  \chi_{D}(x)=\begin{cases}
                 1, & x\in D \\
                 \\
                 0, & x\notin D.
               \end{cases}
\end{equation} 
How can we define $\chi_Du$, for $u\in M\subset L^p[0,1]$? Where $M$ is a bounded subset of $L^p[0,1]$.

Comment: That do you mean with $\chi_Du$? And what kind of set is $M$? Why do you not simply write $u\in L^p[0,1]$?

Comment: By $\chi_Du$ do you mean $\chi_D(u)$ where $\chi_D$ is defined as above?

Comment: The function, $\chi_D$ is just a representant of an $L^p$ function. You can choose $\tilde{u}$ to be a representant of $u$ and $\chi_D\times \tilde{u}$ will be a representant of the product (if you mean that).

Comment: @RuviLecamwasam I guess yes, it must be $\chi_D(u)$. actually I just found this example in an article I was going through and couldn't understand it. It was written just like I did.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Here $M$ is a bounded subset of $L^p[0,1]$. Thanks for pointing out I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @ShinningStar See my edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $\chi_{D}u$ can be defined in that way:
\begin{equation}
  (\chi_{D}u)(x)=\begin{cases}
                 u(x), & x\in D, \\
                 \\
                 0, & x\notin D.
               \end{cases}
\end{equation}

**Edit:** You don't need to mention that $u\in M\subseteq L^p[0,1]$ where $M$ is a bounded subset of $L^p[0,1]$. This is equivalent to $u\in  L^p[0,1]$ without mentioning $M$ at all because for each $u\in  L^p[0,1]$ you can choose $M$ to be $M:=\{u\}$.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Would $\chi_D u\in L^p[0,1]$? If I have to take it's norm what it should be?

Comment: @ShinningStar Since $u\in L^p[0,1]$ and $|\chi_{D}u|\le |u|$ we also have $\chi_{D}u\in L^p[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! :)